# How can I handle duplicates while join two data set in HiveSql

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

user_information table has unique user_id. But the application table contains multiple records for each users. I want to get their age, gender, income values and combine into user_information table.

The below query is postgresql query which i usually use. But I want to perform this task in Hivesql. Could you please help me on this.

```
SELECT
    a.user_id,
    app.*
FROM 
    user_information u
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT distinct on (user_id)
            age,
            gender,
            income
        FROM 
            applications b
        Where
            user_id = u.user_id
    ) app ON TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `distinct on`, use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.*
FROM user_information u LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT (user_id) a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.user_id ORDER BY <something> as seqnum
      FROM applications a
    ) a 
    ON a.user_id = u.user_id AND seqnum = 1;
```

In Postgres, you should be using a an `ORDER BY` when using `DISTINCT ON`.  However, your query does not have an `ORDER BY`, sop it is missing key information.

You should include something in the `ORDER BY` to determine *which* row you want.  If you don't care, the `order by` clause is required.  You *might* be able to use a constant (`ORDER BY NULL`) or use `user_id`.

Comment: applications table has billions of rows. if i use row_number() will it result slow running query?

Comment: @balams . . . Well, yes.  But any operation with the table will be relatively slow.  This does what you want.